# Prove: $1/2(a+b) \times (a - b) = b \times a$ - in three space

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Let $\times$ = cross product and $a$ and $b$ have vector signs on them.

$a = [a_1, a_2, a_3]$

$b = [b_1, b_2, b_3]$

How would I prove this? Do I expand out cross product?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: expand the cross product

Comment: It also might help to draw a picture and it pretty much follows from the picture.

Comment: Exactly what @Jeremy said, you just need to expand the LHS and show that it is equal to the RHS.

Comment: When expanding the cross-product, don't forget that the cross-product operation is anti-commutative ($u\times v==v\times u$) and therefore the cross-product of any vector with itself is zero.

Comment: @Jessica : instead of drawing vector signs, you can write $\mathbf{a}$ using \mathbf{a} surrounding by dollar signs.  It seems difficult to find good-looking vector signs in $\TeX$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\times (a-b) = \frac{1}{2}(a\times a - a\times b +b\times a +b\times b)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}(0+b\times a +b\times a + 0)=b\times a$$

Comment below if you don't follow these manipulations.

Comment: i literally have no idea what you did..

Comment: @Jessica Do you know that the cross product is anti-commutative? That is, $a\times b=-b\times a$?

Comment: yes, but why can you sub in the 3 space vectors to simplify?

Comment: @Jessica What do you mean by "sub in"? There's no substitution here. I'm just using two facts: the cross product is bilinear and anti-commutative.