# How to simplify $(\textbf{a} - \textbf{b})\times(\textbf{a}+\textbf{b})$?

Tags: vectors, 3d, cross-product

Are there any interesting ways of simplifying $(\textbf{a} - \textbf{b})\times(\textbf{a}+\textbf{b})$, where $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are 3D vectors before I begin to dismantle the expression into a mess like a surgeon?

Thanks in advance.

HMA

Comment: Distributive property, anticommutativity. I assume the "mess" you refer to is the formula involving coordinates.

Comment: @runway44 Yes I want to avoid coordinates.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807356/if-u-and-v-are-vectors-in-r3-simplify-the-expression-uv-times-u-v) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602036/prove-1-2ab-times-a-b-b-times-a-in-three-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(\mathbf a-\mathbf b)\times(\mathbf a+\mathbf b)$

$=(\mathbf a-\mathbf b)\times \mathbf a+(\mathbf a-\mathbf b)\times \mathbf b $

$= \mathbf a\times \mathbf a-\mathbf b\times \mathbf a+\mathbf a\times \mathbf b-\mathbf b\times \mathbf b$

$=\mathbf 0+\mathbf a\times \mathbf b + \mathbf a\times \mathbf b - \mathbf 0$

$=2 \;\mathbf a\times \mathbf b$

by distributive, anti-commutative, and self cross product properties.